# Publish Related Items error - Object reference not set to an instance of an object - Sitecore 9 Update 2

Tags: sxa, publishing

I am getting error only for Publish related items. I have installed **sitecore.support.13144.dll** also. No luck after that.

```
Job started: Publish to 'web'|#Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Publication.Pipelines.GetItemReferences.AddReferencedItemsToQueue.AddAllReferences(Item item, PublishOptions options)
   at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Publication.Pipelines.GetItemReferences.AddReferencedItemsToQueue.GetReferencedItems(PublishItemContext context)
   at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Publication.Pipelines.GetItemReferences.AddReferencedItemsToQueue.GetItemReferences(PublishItemContext context)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.GetItemReferences.GetItemReferencesProcessor.Process(PublishItemContext context)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.GetItemReferences.GetItemReferencesPipeline.Run(PublishItemContext context, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem.PublishItemPipeline.Run(PublishItemContext context)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessPublishingCandidate(PublishingCandidate entry, PublishContext context, List`1& referrers, List`1& children)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessPublishingCandidate(PublishingCandidate entry, PublishContext context)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1 entries, PublishContext context)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.Process(PublishContext context)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.PublishPipeline.Run(PublishContext context)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Publisher.PublishWithResult()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.JobRunner.RunMethod(JobArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.Job.DoExecute()
   at Sitecore.Jobs.Job.ThreadEntry(Object state)
```

Comment: Does your tenant/site have any non alphanumerical characters? Like `-`?

Comment: @MarekMusielak : I am trying to publish "Templates"-- /sitecore/templates only. Content items are having name like - "abc-success" under Tenant/site node.

Comment: I'm asking for tenant and site items only. not their children. I thought I had an issue with tenant or site with dash

Comment: @MarekMusielak : My tenant name is like "abc.xyz"

Comment: The `.` character can be the reason. Best try same setup with a tenant without `.`

Answer (score 1):

Verified with Sitecore support and they have given hotfix for it.

`Sitecore.Support.13278` is the patch given by Sitecore support team. You can download it from their support github account here: https://github.com/SitecoreSupport/Sitecore.Support.13278

Comment: Can you add the hotfix number or a link to the hotfix documentation if it is public?

Comment: @Dan Sinclair: Sitecore.Support.13278 is the patch given by Sitecore support team